# How to check JSON is empty in in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I receive following response in an Ajax call:

```
[]
```

I want to check in JQuery whether this is JSON is empty or not? I have tried some ways out:

```
var data = '[]';
try {
json = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(json);
} catch (e) {
alert("Va");
}
```

also tried

```
 if (data.objects.length == 0) {
                $("#divi").html('nothing found');
            }
            else{
               $("#divi").html('Found 10 Objects');
            }
```

but in vein. Could anyone suggest how to check response JSON is an empty JSon or not; in jQuery?

**Update**:

```
 data: {
    '_CONV_ID': $('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val(),
 },
 success: function (data) {
 //Here JSON check to be implemented. I am getting data
 }
```

Comment: `data.length`... or `if(data.objects)`

Comment: try `json.length` where `json = $.parseJSON(data)`

Answer (score 4):

`[]` is an empty array, so

```
var data = '[]';  
$.parseJSON(data);
```

will give you an empty `Array`

so you could do:

```
if ($.parseJSON(data).length) { // 0 as falsey, > 0 as truthy
   //not empty
}else{
   //empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the *parsed* object, not the original `data` (which is just a string):

```
var data = '[]';
json = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(json.length === 0);
```

Which can be used like:

```
if (!json.length) {
    $("#divi").html('nothing found');
}
else {
    $("#divi").html('Found 10 Objects');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> use `json.length` or `jQuery.isEmptyObject()`